# JCL expected continuation not received

Tags: jcl

When starting a job it fails with JCL not run

```
173 IEFC621|  EXPECTED CONTINUATION NOT RECIEVED              
174 IEFC605|  UNIDENTIFIED OPERATIONAL FIELD
```

The code

```
173 //STEP1   EXEC SASDUP,WORKU=SYSDU,WORK='100,25'   
         OPTIONS='MACRO SORTDEV=SYSDU FS                                     X
174 //           SYSPARM=''''2016040120160430'''''
```

Comment: Comma after WORK='100,25' ?

Comment: @MikeT partly, at least. that line "between" 173 and 174 also looks odd.

Comment: Can you post the source JCL for that step and the full expansion from spool file two for the step, pasting from your emulator, not retyping.

Comment: Although seeing exactly what is happening can be fun, general advice would be not to us the "stick something in column 72 to do a continuation" but to use a comma as the final part of a JCL fragment, as @MikeT suggested, and then have a correct JCL fragment following. The column 72 thing is just for backwards compatibility and is not good for new code. Unless your site standards are entirely dumb.

Comment: @Bill re line between 173/174 looking odd. I think it's because it has (if I recall correctly) been interpreted as in-stream data as it doesn't have //, so it's not been given a line number. The x, again if I recall correctly,  should be on line 173 in column 72. However, agree that it's use should be frowned upon. I think line 174 causes both messages. First because of //  (not a new type/operational field) so it is then a continuation BUT due to no comma to indicate continuation. Then because it's // it's not a type or operational field.

Comment: @MikeT I had tried that out. The thing is, the generated-SYSIN message gobbles up the line (because it is data) so you just see the message for generated. I now think the X and not starting where it should has caused the line to be a long "comment" extension of 173, then 174 is just invalid JCL. I may have an attempt to actually recreate it, but so much easier if OP just pastes what they did :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
//STEP1   EXEC SASDUP,
//            WORKU=SYSDU,
//            WORK='100,25',
// OPTIONS='MACRO SORTDEV=SYSDU FS SYSPARM=''''2016040120160430'''''
```

This is just freehand, I haven't tested it.

As @BillWoodger indicates, [continuation can be quite tricky](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=statements-continuing-jcl).

Comment: _continuation can be quite tricky._ especially when using punch-cards :)

Answer (score 0):

So first, there's missing a coma after you "WORK='100,25'" parameter. Second, make sure your continuity of statement never starts after position(cols) 16. It may also be over or under 16 though, depending on your emulator (look were a wrote *here* below). Third, the issue could be into your SASDUP application. Fourth, clean up your OPTION and SORTDEV parameters? I don't think it can work like that.

```
OPTIONS='MACRO SORTDEV=SYSDU FS                                     X
```

?
Take a look at SASDUP, it may help you found which parameters it needs. And so, parameters for SASDUP must be separated with comas and, if on the next line, must begin at a specific position.

Try something like that.

```
//STEP1 EXEC SASDUP,WORKU=SYSDU,WORK='100,25',
  *here*     OPTIONS='MACRO',SORTDEV='SYSDUFSX'
//*here*     SYSPARM='2016040120160430'
```

I'm far from a expert, but I hope it'll help you.

Comment: X is to mark continuation (not the only way, of course. X (or whatever) is more strict, as the JCL Reference will tell you. The issue is clearly notified by the line number by the JCL interpretor. If the OPTIONS is stated correctly, what would "clear it up" mean? You are entirely and 100% wrong about the continued-to line not requiring // in column one. Try it, and wonder why the system has generated a SYSIN DD statement for you.

Comment: *edited* Thanks for your comment. What was I thinking...? of course it needs //